# i3: Title bar and border colors not matching

Tags: configuration, i3

No matter what I do, my i3 config keeps displaying different colors on active windows. This is what it looks like (notice the lighter sidebar compared to the title bar):

[image: screenshot of container]

And this is the relevant part of my config file:

```bash
set $r "#b60000"
set $w "#f4f6ff"
set $g "#23252e"
set $l "#555555"
set $y "#ffff00"
set $b "#000000"

client.focused          $r $r $w $r $r
client.focused_inactive $g $g $l $g $g
client.unfocused        $g $g $l $g $g
client.urgent           $y $y $b $y $y
client.placeholder      $r $r $w $r $r
client.background       $w
```

For some reason (maybe old version, running 4.18.2), I can't set `client.focused_tab_title` ([source](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#client_colors%60)), so hopefully the solution is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally discovered the issue is caused by **compton**'s `inactive-dim` option. Anything higher than zero will cause the issue, so setting `inactive-dim = 0.0` solved it.

Perhaps this can be worked around by adding the borders to `fade-exclude`, but I won't bother with this for now.